# Using a A22680 psu to power a 1000w induction coil

Tags: power-supply

Hoping for some help with my project im struggleing with my A22680 Psu the plan is to use it to power a 1000w induction coil for use in a waste oil heater to keep my workshop warm. I have shorted out the relevant pins to ground and have 48v on the contacts great I thought ,however when I connect my inductor to it the psu shuts off and the warning light is illuminated. Am I missing something? I hoped it was a simple thing to do but it's proving difficult. Thanks In advance [image][image]

Comment: you are missing a description of the A22680 psu and a description of the induction coil.

Comment: how are you using an induction coil in an oil heater?

Comment: Sorry just added some more info, I am using the coil to heat the pipe near the injector in a conventional oil boiler burner. The waste oil needs to be heated in order to burn properly. I had a old burned lying around so I put the pipe in some waste oil but it wouldn't burn so I heated the pipe close to the injector until it was red ish and it worked, so my idea was to use a induction coil the do the heating. Psu seemed to be the cheapest way to power the inductor, I have located the short pkill pin and grounded it out alongwith the pin to the left.

Comment: You do realize that an induction heating coil requires an AC supply, right, not a DC one?

Answer (score 2):

Using a DC power supply to drive an induction coil is absolutely, positively not going to work. Never. You need a driver board (such as you show in your picture) to drive the coil with an AC signal.

What happens with the board you show is that, at the high frequency the board uses, the inductance of the coil produces an impedance which is much higher than the DC resistance, and this sets the power lever produced in the coil.

When you substituted the PSU, it is trying to drive the much (much!) lower DC resistance. This requires more current than the PSU can provide, so it shuts itself off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the driver board in the picture is exactly what i have its a 12-48v 1000w dc inductor. So I bought a 1200w dc 48v power supply hoping it was more than enough.

Comment: Any more ideas guys? really cant see what im missing or not understanding. thanks